# User Register DB Issue

Tags: php, pdo

So, this is a script to dump the user info into the database using the PDO driver.  Whenever I run the script with a unique username it works and it dumps the info in.  But, if a user with the same username tries to sign up it should throw an error.  I'm using $stmt->errorCode() == 23000 to check for duplicates in the database but whenever I try and register a username I've already registered I just get a blank white screen.  I've ran through the script with xDebug and it looks like when I try and sign up with a username that's already in the database it's not even hitting the if/else statements at the bottom of the script.  It's just executing and throwing a blank white screen.

EDIT:  I do have the username field in the DB set to 'unique'.

Video of xDebug walkthrough: http://screencast.com/t/znZfMgV2

Any ideas?

```
// create a salt using the current timestamp
$salt = time();

// encrypt the password and salt
$password = sha1($password.$salt);

// prepare the sql statement
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (created, username, salt, password) VALUES(now(), :username, :salt, :password)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// bind the parameters
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':salt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    $registerResult = "$username has been registered. You may now log in.";
} elseif ($stmt->errorCode() == 23000) {
    $registerResult = "$username is already in use. Please choose another username.";
} else {
    $registerResult = 'Sorry, there was a problem with the database';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for errorcodes will not work, because the duplicate error will throw an exception on the call to `execute()`.

You need to catch `PDOException` :

```
try {
    // create a salt using the current timestamp
    $salt = time();

    // encrypt the password and salt
    $password = sha1($password.$salt);

    // prepare the sql statement
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (created, username, salt, password) VALUES(now(), :username, :salt, :password)';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // bind the parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':salt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
        $registerResult = "$username has been registered. You may now log in.";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($stmt->errorCode() == 23000) {
        $registerResult = "$username is already in use. Please choose another username.";
    } else {
        $registerResult = 'Sorry, there was a problem with the database';
    }
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Make sure your connection is set up to throw exception of course:

```
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Comment: Yes, I have those set in my error config function.

With the solution you provided it does work to an extent but it throws a SQL error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Futanical' for key 'username'" 

I need it to check for a duplication and if there is a duplicate dump the error into the $registerResult variable.

Comment: so what is the issue just dump it into your variable  `$registerResult = $e->getMessage();`

Comment: Derp.  Sorry, brain fart.  Your solution worked perfectly!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are PHP errors disabled? (The blank page makes me think so)
If so, try inserting

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

in your code, maybe the blank page will start having some useful error messages on it.

(Do not use on live server though, obviously)